# select three values based on the group by of alphabets a-z

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a table named 'user' which has fields named 'id','name'.

I need to select three names from each alphabet and display it a page, So total results will be 26*3 = 78.

I have done this using PHP, I need to optimize the query, Can we done this in a single query ?

Comment: I have manually wrote the query with help of php. ie 26 queries

Comment: yes it can be done, post the query you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try with this one:

```
SELECT alphabet, name FROM (
SELECT
LEFT(name, 1) AS alphabet,
name,
@num := IF(@prev = LEFT(name, 1), @num + 1, 1) AS row_num,
@prev := LEFT(name, 1) as previous
FROM yourTable, (SELECT @num:=0, @prev:='') v
ORDER BY name
) sq
WHERE row_num <= 3
```

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have (test) data in your table? In this query there is nothing which restricts data, so regardless if it's right or wrong there should be something as result.

Comment: Yes I am sure, I have around 2500 rows of data in the table. But it shows nothing in the result

Comment: can you post a small dump or even better provide sample data on sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
`SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 0,3` 
I dunno if that is what you asked. Lemme know if its solved!! :)

Comment: I have used this 26 times for each letter, SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 0,3, I need to find a way to do this in a single query.

Comment: Ohh!! Need to think then!! :)